# Division on the fly

Tags: java, division

I'm trying to make a small program in Java which converts Fahrenheit to Celsius. It involves deducting 32 and multiplying by 5/9. So I did this.

```
double Fahrenheit = 100;
double celsius = (Fahrenheit - 32) * (5/9);
System.out.println(celsius);
```

But for some reason that 5/9 returns zero which ruins it all, even

```
double s = 5/9;
```

returns zero and I don't know why.
The only way I found I can do it is if I declare everything and do it slowly, step by step.

```
double x = 5, p = 9, n = (x/p), Fah = 100;
double Cel = Fah - 32;
Cel = Cel*n;
```

Can anyone tell me why this sort of thing happens, I thought at least declaring it as a double would return a value. And if anyone knows, a way round it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Numbers are `int` by default in Java. So when you do `5/9`, since they're both `int`s, you'll get 0.something, and since this is an `int`, only 0 will be stored. Solution:

```
double s = 5.0/9; //or 5d/9
```

Note that you can only *explicitly* cast one side, the other will be *implicitly* cast.

Now the calculation will be in a `double` manner and you'll get the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

or you can do `(5d/9d); // OR (5d/9)` making `5` and `9` explicit `double`

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice, when you deal with doubles, to write code like this:

```
double Fahrenheit = 100.0;
double celsius = (Fahrenheit - 32.0) * (5.0 / 9.0);
```